# Buttons in Auto Py to Exe aren't clickable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I heard about the tool "auto-py-to-exe" but when i open it with

```
auto-py-to-exe
```

the window opens but the language box is empty and no button is clickable.
I tried to reinstall it but the error is happening every time and I don't know why.

[image: The Window]

Is it because i use Chrome or something like that?

Maybe you can help me

Comment: "Is it because i use Chrome" -- did you mean Chrome OS?

Comment: No I'm using the browser Google Chrome and I'm using Windows OS

Comment: Seems like you've encountered a bug.  I would reach out to whomever made that tool and see if they are aware.

Comment: Thanks I will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution because of that I rested my Computer, after that it worked. Maybe it was a wrong Python installation.